# Error While connecting to Oracle, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Tags: c#, oracle

I have been searching for a solution for this in the last two weeks and tried all the methods mentioned across the web, yet to figure out why this is still happening !

I am able to connect to a Oracle DB from SQL Plus but when i try to connect to it from C# its giving the following error.

> {"ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested
>   in connect descriptor"}    System.Exception
>   {Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException}

SQL plus is resolving the connection using LDAP but in C# I have tried the folloiwng connection strings,

```
//string strConnectString = "Data Source=XYZ;User ID=user;Password=pwd";

string strConnectString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ABC1234.Xyz.abc)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XYZ)));User ID=user;Password=pwd";
```

but both connection strings are causing the error, I am using  Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client for connectivity.

Can you experts please direct me in the right direction?

Comment: have you tried setting SID=YOUR_DB_SID instead of  SERVICE_NAME=XYZ?

Comment: Try "CONNECT_DATA=(SID=SID_NAME_HERE)".

Comment: Thanks A Ton Mates... Amazing its working. Just Changed to SID and it starts to work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just changed the connection string with SID instead of Service_Name, Thanks a lot to the good Friends who has guided me in the right direction.

```
string strConnectString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ABC1234.Xyz.abc)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XYZ)));User ID=user;Password=pwd"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I want to connect to oracle database entity framework and I used scaffold-DbContext and changed the reqular form of connection string used in SQLSERVER to the oracle TNS connection string as the following and its working as expected like this :

```
    Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=Kaash-App1.kaash.local)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=kaashm)));User ID=trngkaash;Password=kaashnew" 
-Provider Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore 
-OutputDir    Models 
-Tables  USERS
```