# Error while connecting to Oracle, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oracle

My problem is when I try to make a connection to an Oracle 9i database, when I put the connection string it marks me **"TNS: listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor"** .
I found in a forum a similar error and says that the change the SERVICE_NAME for the SID, make the change but now it marks me that **"INVALID USERNAME / PASSWORD; LOGON DENIED"**.

This is the foro: [Error While connecting to Oracle, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31199903/error-while-connecting-to-oracle-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-servic)

It is clear that I use this class for other connections to Oracle, but they are versions greater than 9i.

Could you help me with this problem.
This is part of the code where I made the connection.

```
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace InterfaceMonterrey.Models
{
public class Ora_Conexion_ADQUIS
{
    private OracleConnection cn { get; set; }

    public OracleConnection getConn()
    {
        if (cn == null)
        {
            //string conexion = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CONEXION_ORACLE_ADQUIS"].ToString();
/*string conexion = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxx.xx.xxx.x)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xxx)));User Id = ABC; Password = and123;";*/
            string conexion = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxx.xx.xxx.x)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=xxx)));User Id = ABC; Password = and123;";
            cn = new OracleConnection(conexion);

        }
        return cn;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For version Oracle 9i, the username and password are not case sensitive.
But if a special character such as "@" is found in the password, the character must be  screened.

Example 1, for Windows

```
C:\oracle\ora92\bin>sqlplus.exe SCOTT/\"T@GER\"@test-ecdu

SQL*Plus: Release 9.2.0.1.0 - Production on Thu Nov 28 07:35:30 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2002, Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.8.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP and Oracle Data Mining options
JServer Release 9.2.0.8.0 - Production

connected>
```

Example 2, for Linux

```
 #!/usr/bin/ksh

username=SCOTT
password=\"t@ger\"

TNS_ALIAS='(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxxx.yyy.zzz)(PORT = 1521))
        (CONNECT_DATA =
         (SERVER = DEDICATED)
         (ORACLE_SID = test)
    )
)'

echo username:  $username
echo password:  $password
echo TNS_ALIAS: $TNS_ALIAS

sqlplus  $username/$password@"$TNS_ALIAS" @test.sql



oracle@esmd:~> ./test3.ksh
username: SCOTT
password: "t@ger"
TNS_ALIAS: (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxxx.yyy.zzz)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (ORACLE_SID = test) ) )

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Thu Nov 28 07:55:51 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.8.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP and Oracle Data Mining options
JServer Release 9.2.0.8.0 - Production


TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD
-------------------
28-11-2019 07:55:53

Disconnected from Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.8.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP and Oracle Data Mining options
JServer Release 9.2.0.8.0 - Production
oracle@esmd:~>
```

Comment: Hi @Dmitry this would look like this 
 : string conexion = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxx.xx.xxx.x)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=xxx)));User Id = ABC; Password = @and@123;";?

Comment: Try to screen the special character such as "@" in password. password=\"@and@123;\"

Comment: I tried to put it as you mentioned but I still throw the same error
This is my string connection: Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=000.0.000.0)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=MTR)));User Id = adquis; Password =\"@admty160701@;"\

Comment: Password=\"@admty160701@;\"